# Splitting one dictionary item into 2 variables

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to split one dictionary value into 2 separate variables. For example the data I am trying to split is "Example":{"type":"Point","points":[14.670275,121.043955]}. I know that if I wanted the points as a whole it would look like:

```
VariA = tDict['Example']['points']
```

But what if I want the two coordicates to be separate variables? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `p1, p2 = tDict['points']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tDict['Example']['points']` is just a list, so:

```
p1 = tDict['Example']['points'][0]
p2 = tDict['Example']['points'][1]
```

Or if you are unkeen about accessing the dictionary twice (not that it matters..):

```
points = tDict['Example']['points']
p1 = points[0]
p2 = points[1]
```

Or in a single line and a single access:

```
p1, p2 = tDict['Example']['points']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = tDict['Example']['points']
```

It's called tuple unpacking. If you also want `VariA` you can do:

```
x, y = VariA = tDict...
```